# CSS, Bootstrap4 Cards Lado a Lado

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

bom dia! Tudo bem?

estou tendo dificuldades com o bootstrap 4, quando se usa os cards eu gostaria que eles se alinhassem lado a lado, porém os mesmos ficam um abaixo do outro e eu nao sei como conseguir deixar eles lado a lado, alem do mais o container ficam margens gigantes nas laterais, e quando usei o .container-fluid na esperança de solucionar o problema ele ficou com uma mini margem nas duas laterais e eu nao sei como remove-las, ja tentei o margin: 0px; e padding: 0px; e nada resolve, poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Sei que a dúvida é iniciante mas gostaria muito de uma luz com isso.

Abaixo o HTML e o CSS, fiz algumas mudanças para ficar melhor para o stack porém deve ter perdido um pouco da indexação perfeitinha, mas garanto que no código está bem organizado. Obrigado!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Core Store</title>

 </head>

 <body>
    <div = class="container-fluid">
     <header class="header">
        <a href="corestore.html"><img id="logo"src="public\img\logo.gif"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="http://coresolutions.com.br/core-solutions-it">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>
    <main>
        <h1>Produtos</h1>
        <div id="card1" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub1.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card2" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub2.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card3" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub3.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card4" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub3.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card5" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub5.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card6" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub4.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
                </div>
        </div>
<div id="card7" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub5.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card8" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub6.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="anuncio" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub4.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </main> 
    <aside><p>teste</p></aside>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<footer><p class="text-center">Feito por GFB</p></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>






body, ul, li, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: arial;
}.container-fluid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 96fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "h h h"
                         "a m m"
                         "f f f"
    }
body {
}
main {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: m;
}
aside {
    background-color: purple;
    grid-area: a;
}
footer {
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-area: f;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.header {
    background-color: #101010;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: h;
}
.logo{
margin-left: 20px;
height: 100px;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
}
.menu li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #008B8B;
    color: white;
}
.card {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inclua os cards em uma div `.container-fluid` e adicione outras classes nativas do Bootstrap 4 para converter em flexbox:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-wrap">
   COLOQUE OS CARDS AQUI
</div>
```

Como você está alterando a classe nativa `.container-fluid` no seu CSS, troque o nome da classe por outro para não bagunçar a classe do Bootstrap. Por exemplo, pode usar a classe `.grid`. Troque:

```
.container-fluid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 96fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "h h h"
                         "a m m"
                         "f f f"
}
```

Por:

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 96fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "h h h"
                         "a m m"
                         "f f f"
}
```

E na div principal (a que vem logo após a abertura do `body`) adicione a classe `.grid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid grid">
```

Outro problema é o `margin-top` no `<h1>`. Remova-o pois ele cria um espaço em vazio entre a div onde ele está e o `header`.

Em vez disso, coloque um `padding-top` no `main` com o valor que você quer dar o espaçamento.

Seu código ficará assim:

```css
body, ul, li, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: arial;
}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 96fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "h h h"
                         "a m m"
                         "f f f"
}
body {
}
main {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: m;
    padding-top: 50px;

}
aside {
    background-color: purple;
    grid-area: a;
}
footer {
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-area: f;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    /*margin-top: 100px;*/
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.header {
    background-color: #101010;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: h;
}
.logo{
margin-left: 20px;
height: 100px;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
}
.menu li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #008B8B;
    color: white;
}
.card {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid grid">
  <header class="header">
     <a href="corestore.html"><img id="logo"src="public\img\logo.gif"></a>
     <nav>
         <ul class="menu">
             <li><a href="http://coresolutions.com.br/core-solutions-it">Sobre</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
  </header>
 <main>
     <h1>Produtos</h1>
     <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-wrap">
     <div id="card1" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub1.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div id="card2" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub2.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div id="card3" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub3.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div id="card4" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub3.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
         <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
             <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="card5" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub5.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
             </div>
     </div>
     <div id="card6" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub4.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
             </div>
     </div>
      <div id="card7" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub5.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
             </div>
     </div>
     <div id="card8" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub6.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
             </div>
     </div>
     <div id="anuncio" class="card" style="width: 300px;">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="public\img\tub4.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">Um exemplo de texto rápido para construir o título do card e fazer preencher o conteúdo do card.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Visitar</a>
             </div>
     </div>
     </div>
 </main>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Me ajudou demais!!

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Para você trabalhar com *Bootstrap*, o correto é utilizar o sistema de **grids** do mesmo. Então para resolver seu problema, basta colocar cada *card* dentro de uma coluna, a estrutura correta seria mais ou menos a seguinte:

```
<div class='row'>

     <div class='col-3'>

          <div class='card'>
               ...
          </div>

     </div>

     <div class='col-6'>

          <div class='card'>
               ...
          </div>

     </div>

     <div class='col-3'>

          <div class='card'>
               ...
          </div>

     </div>

</div>
```

No exemplo acima eu crio uma linha (`row`), e dentro dela eu coloco as colunas (`col`). A soma do valor dessas colunas **não pode ser maior do que 12**, pois senão vai quebrar o seu layout. Fazendo isso, os seus `card` vão automaticamente ficar lado a lado, e em dispositivos mobile vão ficar responsivos. ;)

Se quiser entender um pouco mais, to deixando o link da documentação do Bootstrap em português para você entender um pouco sobre o grid: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Espero que tenha ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Obrigado! Me ajudou muito tbm

Answer (score 2):

Olá, bom tem várias formas de abordar esse tema, sendo flexbox, ou grid....
Segue um exemplo prático de utilização do flexbox

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>

    <title>Bootstrap - Classes flexbox</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style type="text/css">
      .caixa {
        background: #f5f5f5;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .item {
        border:1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <h2>Flex container e flex itens (d-flex, flex-row, flex-column, flex-row-reverse)</h2>
      <div class="caixa d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <div class="item">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
      <br><br>

      <h2>Alinhamento horizontal: justify-content-ALINHAMENTO (start, center, end, around e between)</h2>
      <div class="caixa d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="item">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
      <br><br>

      <h2>Colunas (d-flex, flex-column, flex-column-reverse)</h2>
      <div class="caixa d-flex flex-column-reverse">
        <div class="item">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
      <br><br>

      <h2>Alinhamento vertical: align-items-ALINHAMENTO (start, center, end, baseline e stretch)</h2>
      <div class="caixa d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="item" style="padding-top: 30px;">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="item" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
      <br><br>

      <h2>Alinhamento self: align-self-ALINHAMENTO (start, center, end, baseline e stretch)</h2>
      <div class="caixa d-flex">
        <div class="item align-self-start">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="item align-self-center">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="item align-self-end">Flex item 3</div>
        <div class="item align-self-baseline">Flex item 4</div>
        <div class="item align-self-stretch">Flex item 5</div>
      </div>
      <br><br>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso eu teria que retirar todo o CSS GRID do meu código correto? e nao gostaria de fazer isso pois ele me ajuda a deixar organizado no template que quero, usei somente no header o flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

Olá!!

Então... A princípio precisamos entender como funciona o html:

O html funciona em um esquema que exibe um elemento por linha(sem css), então no padrão
dele, cada controle criado corresponde a uma linha e então ele sempre irá "*quebrar*" antes
de inserir outro controle. Isto pode ser manipulado no *css*.

O ***BootStrap*** tem um comportamento definido através de classes onde você pode manipular linhas e colunas para exibir de forma simétrica(ou não) e organizada os seus controles.

A Classe ***Row*** trabalha para que todos ou o máximo possível de controles dentro dela
sejam exibidos em uma única linha, caso o tamanho ultrapasse o tamanho da tela, ele quebra o conteúdo.

Ex:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card column-md-3">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card column-md-3">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card column-md-3">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card column-md-3">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

De forma grosseira, podemos ter com mais algum *css* o seguinte estilo:

[image: Exemplo de tratamento.]

A **Linha Vermelha** faz referencia ao comportamento da *row*, exibindo o conteúdo na mesma linha.

As **Linhas Azuis** fazem referencia ao comportamento das *columns* que podem ser trabalhadas mais a frente.

**Utilize** a classe ***row*** para este caso, e adicione a quantidade de cartões que quiser por linha, a cada linha utilize uma "*div class="row"*".

Conteúdo para consulta sobre o ***sistema de grade do bootstrap***:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/